Channel Divinity: Artisan's Blessing + Crafting an Item = Time?
Say our Cleric is trying to make a set of Plate and has acquired 750 Gold or 4 houses worth of copper pipe.
Crafting an item requires raw materials equal to 1/2 an items selling cost presumably for the actual forging portion. If the Cleric used Artisan's Blessing to create a component of the suit a couple pieces at a time. In 2.5 days he'd have all the plates and straps. Jumping back to crafting would it be reasonable to calculate the time based upon the remaining component the padding at 5gp?
So with sufficient rest and a lot of stolen goods a Forge Cleric can coalesce and assemble a set of plate in about a week.

What are "4 houses worth of copper pipe."?

I am not 100% sure about your question. Are you asking whether a forge cleric can create a Suit of Plate Armor faster than it can be crafted?

Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157847/can-a-forge-cleric-use-artisans-blessing-multiple-times-to-create-parts-of-an-i https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141182/what-are-the-balance-implications-of-allowing-forge-clerics-to-gradually-create?noredirect=1&lq=1

@TreeSpawned "4 houses worth of copper pipe" . . . you know . . . it's when fantasy petty criminals remove all the fantasy copper pipe from fantasy unattended houses to sell it for coin.  Maybe not petty criminals though.  In a typical D&D setting, say the Forgotten Realms, I think only well-to-do houses would have much in the way of copper pipe.  I'm surprised they didn't strip the fantasy wiring while they were at it.

Fill three bags of holding with copper stolen from the nobles mansions is the best quest for gathering raw materials a smith could ever give.

Not as written, but this might be a fine houserule
As the rules are written, using Artisans blessing would not speed up crafting, unless you can create the entire item in one go with it. But talk with your DM, because this is an area where ruling over rule seems very reasonable, and the game tells you (Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p. 4)

The DM is key. Many unexpected events can occur in
a D&D campaign, and no set of rules could reasonably
account for every contingency. If the rules tried to do so,
the game would become a s log. An alternative would be
for the rules to severely limit what characters can do,
which would be contrary to the open-endedness of D&D.
He re's the path the game takes: it lays a foundation of
rules that a DM can build on, and it embraces the DM's
role as the bridge between the things the rules address
and the things they don't.

The rules
The Crafting (p. 187, PHB) downtime rule says

For every day of downtime you spend crafting, you
can craft one or more items with a total market value
not exceeding 5 gp, and you must expend raw materials
worth half the total market value. If something you
want to craft has a market value greater than 5 gp, you
make progress every day in 5-gp increments until you
reach the market value of the item. For example, a suit
of plate armor (market value 1,500 gp) takes 300 days
to craft by yourself.

As written, crafting transforms raw materials. The general accepted consensus is that raw materials just means something used to make something else, whether crude or processed. So a partial piece of armor can work as your input.
However the way the crafting rule is written, the form or state of raw materials does not matter. To craft the item to make progress every day in 5-gp increments. It's independent of having preprocessed armor pieces or such.
Artisan's blessing says:

You conduct an hour-long ritual that crafts a nonmagical item that must include some metal: a simple or martial weapon, a suit of armor, ten pieces of ammunition, a set of tools, or another metal object. [...]
The thing you create can be something that is worth no more than 100 gp. As part of this ritual, you must lay out metal, which can include coins, with a value equal to the creation.

So this channeling option only allows you to create an object of up to 100 gp value, which is far below the value of the full plate armor. It also would allow you to transform copper pipe you ripped out of some buildings into armor pieces, because copper is metal and the armor pieces contain metal. If you use the thing you created as raw materials for crafting however, all that matters is its value. The value did not change, so there is no speed up.
House-ruling on it
That said, I think it would entirely make sense from a narrative perspective to allow the armor pieces created with Artisan's Blessing to count as finished stretches of crafting that armor.
You probably still need some way to unite the various pieces, and very large pieces of the plate, like the breastplate piece may be entirely out of reach of your Artisan's Blessing (a breastplate armor in itself costs 400 gp, and even if it consists of two larger subunits for front and back and some other stuff like helmet or padding and straps, each of them likely is more expensive than 100 gp).
So if your DM allowed this maybe it wouldn't cut the work down to just 1,500/100 = 15 times channeling, but maybe you could do smaller pieces, and the overall time would be somewhere in between 300 days and a few days of intense channeling and short resting effort. But all of that is up to your DM.

I guess it breaks down to the component value of the item being it's relative craft value. The breast plate being a perfect example. It costs 200 gold to craft which perfectly breaks down to 100 gold for each side. Since Artisan's Blessing can create everything from plates, buckles, and straps of leather. In a days time you can manifest both halves of the breastplate.  So then crafting a breastplate would lie between 1 and 56 days.  I think we're on the right track though.
